# How much of a shrimp is meat?

Tags: seafood, shrimp

How much of a shrimp is meat, in percentage?

Read on google that the head is 35%, shell is 15% and meat 50%,

is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my own experience with weighing, 50% meat is correct.

Comment: It's going to be close in most cases, maybe some variation between varieties.